# Why router.matched event is never fired in Lumen 5.3?

Tags: php, lumen

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['events']->listen('router.matched', function () {
        $this->app->resolving(function (FormRequest $request, $app) {
            $this->initializeRequest($request, $app['request']);

            $request->setContainer($app)
                ->setRedirector($app['Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector']);
        });
    });
}
```

It's a boot method in my custom service provider that I registered in `bootstrap/app.php`. I use `Lumen 5.3` framework.

Comment: Because that event doesn't exist, and therefore never gets fired. The `router.matched` event was something that was a part of Laravel 4.1, but was removed in later versions. It was never a part of Lumen. I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do, but it's likely you'll need to think of a different way of handling this.

Answer (score 2):

`Lumen` uses a different router than `Laravel` does. `Lumen` uses the [nikic/fast-route](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) package for a router, whereas Laravel uses the [illuminate/routing](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing) package. Only the full `Laravel` router fires an even when the route is matched.

As a side note, the event fired was `router.matched` up through 5.1. In 5.2, the router was updated to fire the `Events\RouteMatched` event object. However, no events are fired from the router used by `Lumen`.